# Android button border shape with cut corners

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Is it possible to make a button (or any other element like image view or layout) with border shaped with cut corners like below:
[image: rectangle with cut corners]
Preferably using xml-drawables with cut size taken from @dimen

Edit: The important thing is shape should consist of frame only without filling the inside with any color.

Comment: You could use [CornerCutLinearLayout](https://github.com/Devlight/CornerCutLinearLayout), there are other options like CutCornerShape as well.

Comment: @Torima I am unsure if this can produce the layout with only a frame, all I can see in readme are solid filled backgrounds. Are you able to provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    android:text="@string/add_address"
    app:cornerRadius="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_phone"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

and in style file add this

```
<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

in material button change the shape to

```
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent"
```

final result:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    android:text="@string/add_address"
    app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_phone"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

[image]

you can change radius in style file

```
<item name="cornerSize">16dp</item> // here change value
```

Comment: This works as presented in your answer, however I am looking for a shape with frame only.

Comment: you material provide that change style to outLine Button https://material.io/components/buttons/android#outlined-button